# Cost function equation parsing

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to solve this assignment:

> For the cost function​ below, where C is the cost of producing x units of a​ product, find the​ marginal-cost function. What is the marginal cost at the given value of​ x? **C(x)=0.05x^3+0.8x^2+40x+100**; x=500

How could I parse the bolded values, the formula, from this string? Something where this could be repeated with similar strings.

Comment: you could try to split the string in singular operations and at the same time replace operators with function's call

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, it breaks down the equation into objects that need to be summed up and then evaluates each of them on its own:

```
def clean(string):
    # Removes unnecesarry parts of input
    return string.rstrip(';').split('=')[1]

def parse(string):
    parts = string.split('+')

    objs = []
    for part in parts:
        mult_pow = part.split('x')
        if len(mult_pow) == 2:
            # Both multiplier and power present
            obj = (
                float(mult_pow[0]),
                float(mult_pow[1].lstrip('^')) if mult_pow[1] else 1.0
            )
        else:
            if '^' in mult_pow[0]:
                # Only power present
                obj = (
                    1.0,
                    float(mult_pow[0].lstrip('^'))
                )
            else:
                # Only multiplier present
                obj = (
                    float(mult_pow[0]),
                    0
                )
        
        objs.append(obj)

    return objs

def evaluate(parsed_objects, x):
    result = 0
    for obj in parsed_objects:
        result += obj[0] * x**obj[1]
    return result

def solve(equation, x):
    cleaned_str = clean(equation)
    parsed_objects = parse(cleaned_str)
    result = evaluate(parsed_objects, x)
    return result

x = 500
input_str = 'C(x)=0.05x^3+0.8x^2+40x+100;'
result = solve(input_str, x)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
6470100.0
```